# OmniPay SagePay Server method - RedirectionURL 5006 error

Tags: php, payment-gateway, opayo, omnipay

To give you some background, I wrote a payment class that wraps around PaypalExpress and SagePayDirect using Omnipay. It was working, but then, I also needed to add SagePayServer. Unfrotunately after three days of work, I haven't been able to get SagePayServer working. I keep getting the "RedirectionURL 5006" error which is just a catch-all error. SagePay is definitely caling my url, but for some reason, the payment fails and it gives this error.

SagePay and OmniPay both have atrocious documentation and a lack of good working examples so any help is appreciated.

Here's the core of my code (with loads of adjustments to make it simpler for Stack Overflow):

```
<?php

use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class PaymentHandler {

    public
        $transactionID;

    private
        $gateway,
        $config,
        $card,
        $order,
        $options;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->order = new Order();
        $this->createTransactionID();
        $this->setOptions();
        $this->gateway = Omnipay::create("SagePay_Server");
        $this->gateway->setTestMode($this->options["testMode"]);
        $this->gateway->setVendor($this->options["vendorName"]);
    }

    private function prepareSagePayServer() {
        $billingAddress = $this->order->getAddresses("billing");
        $shippingAddress = $this->order->getAddresses("delivery");

        $billingCountry = $this->getCountryISO($billingAddress["country"]);
        $shippingCountry = $this->getCountryISO($shippingAddress["country"]);

        $this->card = array(
            'firstName' => $billingAddress["firstname"],
            'lastName' => $billingAddress["surname"],
            'billingFirstName' => $billingAddress["firstname"],
            'billingLastName' => $billingAddress["surname"],
            'billingAddress1' => $billingAddress["addr1"],
            'billingAddress2' => $billingAddress["addr2"],
            'billingCity' => $billingAddress["city"],
            'billingPostcode' => $billingAddress["postcode"],
            'billingState' => $billingAddress["county"],
            'billingCountry' => $billingCountry,
            'shippingFirstName' => $shippingAddress["firstname"],
            'shippingLastName' => $shippingAddress["surname"],
            'shippingAddress1' => $shippingAddress["addr1"],
            'shippingAddress2' => $shippingAddress["addr2"],
            'shippingCity' => $shippingAddress["city"],
            'shippingPostcode' => $shippingAddress["postcode"],
            'shippingState' => $shippingAddress["county"],
            'shippingCountry' => $shippingCountry
        );
    }

    public function pay() {
        $this->prepareSagePayServer();

        $params = array(
            "description"   => $this->options["description"],
            "amount"    => $this->calculateAmount(),
            "currency"  => "GBP",
            "returnUrl"     => $this->options["confirmURL"],
            "transactionId" => $this->transactionID,
            "card" => $this->card
        );

        try {
            $response = $this->gateway->purchase($params)->send();
            $this->createTransaction($response);

            if($response->isSuccessful()) {
                // never used
            }
            else if ($response->isRedirect()) {
                $response->redirect();
            }
            else {
                $this->redirectToError();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->createTransaction($e);
            $this->redirectToError();
        }
    }

    public function confirm() {
        $params = array(
            "transactionId" => $this->transactionID,
            "transactionReference" => $this->retrieveTransactionReference()
        );

        try {
            $response = $this->gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();
            $this->updateTransactionStatus($response);

            if($response->isSuccessful()) {
                $response->confirm($this->options["completeURL"]);
            }
            else {
                $response->confirm($this->options["errorURL"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $request = $this->gateway->completePurchase(array());
            $response = new \Omnipay\SagePay\Message\ServerCompleteAuthorizeResponse($request, array());
            $this->updateTransactionStatus($response);
            $this->redirectToError();
        }
    }

    public function complete() {
        $transaction = $this->retrieveTransaction();
        $this->order->orderComplete($transaction);
    }

    private function setOptions() {
        global $sagepayConfig;
        $this->options = $sagepayConfig;
        $this->buildURLParameters();
    }

    private function redirectToError() {
        header("Location: " . $this->options["errorURL"]);
        exit();
    }

    private function parseTransactionRef($rawTransactionRef) {
        // The implementation is not included here.
        return $transactionRef;
    }

    private function createTransaction($data) {
        // The implementation is not included here.
    }

    private function retrieveTransactionReference() {
        // The implementation is not included here.
        return $rawTransactionRef;
    }

    private function retrieveTransaction() {
        // The implementation is not included here.
        return $transaction;
    }

    private function createTransactionID() {
        if(isset($_GET["transactionid"])) {
            $this->transactionID = htmlspecialchars($_GET["transactionid"]);
            // test the validity of the transaction id and throw an error if invalid
        }
        else {
            $this->transactionID = $this->order->id . "-" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
        }
    }

    private function updateTransactionStatus($data) {
        // The implementation is not included here.
    }

    private function getStatusUpdates() {
        // The implementation is not included here.
        return $statusUpdates;
    }

    private function buildStatusUpdate($newStatus, $statusLog = "[]") {
        // The implementation is not included here.
        return $statusLog;
    }

    private function buildURLParameters() {
        $urls = array("confirmURL", "completeURL", "errorURL");
        $params = array(
            "transactionid" => $this->transactionID
        );
        foreach ($urls as $urlName) {
            $url = $this->options[$urlName];
            $parsedURL = parse_url($url);
            $queries = array();
            if(isset($parsedURL["query"])) {
                parse_str($parsedURL["query"], $queries);
            }
            $queries = array_merge($queries, $params);
            $parsedURL["query"] = http_build_query($queries);
            $this->options[$urlName] = http_build_url($parsedURL);
        }
    }

    private function getCountryISO($countryPrintName) {
        // The implementation is not included here.
        return $countryISO;
    }

    private function calculateAmount() {
        // The implementation is not included here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this, or are you still waiting for an answer? I think this big lump of code just gives nobody any clues what you have tried, what the context is, and exactly where you are having problems.